# Is returning void valid code?

Tags: c++, c, return, void

I found out that the following code gets accepted by Visual C++ 2008 and GCC 4.3 compilers:

```
void foo()
{

}

void bar()
{
  return foo();
}
```

I am a bit surprised that it compiles. Is this a language feature or is it a bug in the compilers? What do the C/C++ standards say about this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's a language feature of C++

C++ (ISO 14882:2003) 6.6.3/3

> A return statement with an expression of type “cv void” can be used only in functions with a return type of cv void; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller.

C (ISO 9899:1999) 6.8.6.4/1

> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is void.

Comment: Note that many compilers that can compile both C and C++ will offer the C++ rule as a non-standard extension while compiling C code, although this shouldn't be relied on if you want to be portable.

Answer (score 51):

Yes, it is valid code.  This is necessary when you have template functions so that you can use uniform code.  For example,

```
template<typename T, typename P>
T f(int x, P y)
{
  return g(x, y);
}
```

Now, `g` might be overloaded to return void when the second argument is some particular type.  If "returning void" were invalid, the call to `f` would then break.

Comment: `T` can't be void, because a parameter cannot be void.

Comment: Thanks,I've realized myself a few minutes after that I've given a bad example. Fixed!

Comment: This feature also opens a little trap: in `void positive_action(int n) { if (n<0) return; action(n); [...] }`, if `action` returns void, then forgetting the semicolon after `return` will give no errors or warnings, but `action` now get called whe `n` is negative rather than when it is positive.

Comment: Compilers can also use it as a hint that they should be doing tail call optimisation, which can be useful if `f()` is called frequently.

Answer (score 5):

This is valid and can be quite useful for example to create cleaner code in situations when you want to do some error handling before returning:

```
void ErrRet(int code, char* msg)
{
   // code logging/handling error
}
void f()
{
   if (...) return ErrRet(5, "Error Message !");
   // code continue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid indeed. I use it often for input validation macros:

```
#define ASSERT_AND_RETURN_IF_NULL(p,r) if (!p) { assert(p && "#p must not be null"); return r; }

bool func1(void* p) {
  ASSERT_AND_RETURN_IF_NULL(p, false);
  ...
}

void func2(void* p) {
  ASSERT_AND_RETURN_IF_NULL(p, void());
  ...
}
```