# Pass a function returning void to a function accepting void?

Tags: c++

So, after fiddling around for some time, I can't get it... why would this not already be part of standard?

```
template<class T> accept_all(T) {}
void give_void() {}
int give_int() { return 1;}

int main() {
accept_all(give_void());
accept_all(give_int());
}
```

This would save quite a bit of hassle using template class specializations... And in terms of general syntax, it makes little sense to be able to return a void and not being able to pass one.

Is there something I can do that doesn't involve specializing an ugly 'mediator class' for each method type to just call this thing?

Thanks.

EDIT:
What would be a good way to implement a template that accepts any function return value, then?

Comment: why would you implement a function accepting any function return value?

Comment: A problem is that `void` isn't a value, it is no value at all. If you look at `give_void`, it isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 3):

I think it looks really strange. Why just not to call these functions consecutive:

```
give_void();
accept_void();
```

Much more clean.

And actually you save nothing by typing `accept_void(give_void());` even the numbers of symbols you need to enter is the same.

**EDIT** not sure I really understand what you want to achieve, but:

```
template <typename Result, typename Callable>
static Result func(Callable c)
{
    return c();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows you to `return void` from a function (see [Is returning void valid code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383090/c-c-is-returning-void-a-valid-code)).

However, returning void is significantly different from accepting void; note that `int foo(void)` is just an alternate (and deprecated) syntax for `int foo()`, and only exists for historical reasons of compatibility with C.

Your suggestion breaks the invariant that the number of arguments in a function call is the same as the number of arguments the function accepts.

Comment: The standard is confusing (as always). My life would be simpler, if passing a void would never be a 'real' argument, but a syntactical tool to express a dummy. I'm kinda torn between having proxy template classes handle special cases and the language just enabling void arguments as an extension of the template syntax.