# Base conversion using recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I'm working on an assignment and have it partially solved.
Currently I'm getting the correct output, only in reverse.

Here's the helper function I've implemented:

```
char int2char (int radix, int value) {

    char c = '?';

    if ((value >= 0 && value < radix) && (radix <= 36 && radix >= 2)){
        if (value < 10){
            c = value + 48;
        }
        else if (value >= 10 && value < 36) {
            c = value + 55;
        }   
    }

    return c;
}
```

And the actual function I'm having difficulty with looks like this thus far:

```
void int2str (int radix, int value) {

    int result = value % radix;
    int division = value / radix;
    char c;

    c = int2char(radix, result);
    putchar(c);

    while (division > 0) {
        return int2str(radix, division);
    }

}
```

The first function is used to represent the digits 10-35 in hex. So if the modulus produces an 11, for example, I'm supposed to output a 'B'.

This is working great, except backwards! And I can't figure out how to reverse it. The biggest hitch is you can only use putchar() as an output. No strings, no arrays.

To further clarify, if I enter:

```
int2str 16 60
```

The output should be '3C', instead I'm getting 'C3'.

Comment: what happens if you flush() after you putchar()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your use of `while` is confusing, since there's a `return` in it. Replace that with `if`. The `return` is unnecessary, since the function will return on its own at the end.

Once you've done that, you can reverse the output by moving the `putchar` after the recursive call:

```
if (division > 0) {
    int2str(radix, division);
}

putchar(c);
```

---

As a side note, `return int2str(radix, division);` doesn't make sense in this function anyway, since it's a `void` function, so there's nothing to return. If you *did* want to do this (you don't in this case), you would say:

```
somefunction();
return;
```

---

Also, this may be more clear if you used `'0'` and `'A'` instead of 48 and 55:

```
    if (value < 10){
        c = value + '0';
    }
    else if (value >= 10 && value < 36) {
        c = value - 10 + 'A';
    }
```

Comment: That is what I though too, only then I get the '3', and nothing else. That's why I'm so confused? In recursive functions I've built before simply moving the print statement before/after the recursive call will reverse the output. Here it only prints the last modulus operation done.

Comment: @shparkison The confusing part is your unnecessary `return`. Try this updated version.

Comment: @shparkison For more on the side note that he posted, read the top answer from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383090/is-returning-void-a-valid-code

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks for the heads up Brendan. It was definitely the return that was goofing things up.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is the last digit, but you're printing it first. Drop the `return` from the recursive call and move the `putchar` to the end. Also, the `while` loop should be an `if`.

```
void int2str(int radix, int value) {

    int lastdigit = value % radix;
    int firstdigits = value / radix;

    if (firstdigits) {
        int2str(radix, firstdigits);
    }

    putchar(int2char(radix, lastdigit));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
c = int2char(radix, result);

if (division > 0) 
     int2str(radix, division);
putchar(c);
```

Last call to `int2str` will print first digit while first call will print last digit.