# Function templates and void

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Why am I getting an error in the following code? How can i resolve it?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
    std::cout << "::foo() \n";
    return 0;
}

void bar()
{
    std::cout << "::bar() \n";
}

template <typename T>
T Hook(const std::function<T()>& action, T def = T())
{
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {

    }
    catch (...)
    {

    }
    return def;
};

int main()
{
    std::function<int()> foo_func(foo);
    Hook(foo_func);

    std::function<void()> bar_func(bar);
    // Hook(bar_func); // Error
}
```

Comment: You're trying to return a void value?

Comment: @Shaggi Yes, i can do it - http://ideone.com/0835o2

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: that `catch` without rethrowing doesn't bode well

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It's obviously a simplified example, we don't know what those catches do (yet in that case he could have left away the exception stuff entirely anyway, but well).

Comment: @FrozenHeart voids cant have values per se, you're creating a lvalue of type void, as far as i can see, and returning it. Not legal.

Answer (score 4):

When asking about a compiler/linker error, **always** include the error in your question.

Nevertheless, the problem is that `bar` returns `void`, which means the template argument for `Hook`'s `T` is deduced to `void`. And then, for the default argument for `def`, you're trying to create an object of type `void`. That's of course illegal.

You'll have to provide a specialisation (or better, an overload) of `Hook` for `void` functions:

```
template <typename T>
T Hook(const std::function<T()>& action, T def = T())
{
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {

    }
    catch (...)
    {

    }
    return def;
};


void Hook(const std::function<void()>& action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {

    }
    catch (...)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: You beat me to it ;-)

Comment: Can you still `return action()` in the `void` case?

Comment: @ChristianRau Probably not, C&P error. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @Angew Well, I'm not sure, that's why I asked. But from your comment I deduce you're not completely sure either?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Seems legit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383090/is-returning-void-a-valid-code