# Returning void function from a void function

Tags: c

I can do the following:

```
static int16_t foo (void);

static int16_t bar (void) {
    return foo();
}
```

But my compiler complains about

```
static void foo (void);

static void bar (void) {
    return foo();
}
```

Does ANSI C not allow void functions to return void functions? why?

Comment: That first example shouldn't work either. Are you sure it does?

Comment: Forgot to add the parenthesis, on the function calls at return, edited to add them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is returning void valid code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383090/is-returning-void-valid-code)

Comment: Somewhat, but indirectly. The reply here that I have already selected here as the answer is the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `bar` to return `foo`, then you have to change the return type of `bar` so that it returns a `function that takes void and returns void` instead of just `void`:

```
static (void (*)(void)) bar(void) {
    return foo;
}
```

Also, that first example shouldn't work either.

**Edit based on your edit:** you can't (shouldn't) `return` any data from a `void` function. `void` is the absence of data. In C, you can only `return;` from a function that is declared as returning `void` -- you can't `return <data>;` from it.

So `foo()` does not give you any data. It can only be used as a statement, not as an expression.

`return foo();` therefore does not make sense in two ways: the first is that `bar` may not return anything as it is declared to return `void`, and the second is that even if `bar` *does* return an actual data type, `foo()` is still of type `void` and you cannot `return` that.

The first example works because both `foo` and `bar` return `int16_t`s, which are actual data.

Answer (score 5):

It is an error to try to return a value from a function declared to not return a value.

Don't do that.

Also, I really hope your compiler complains about implicitly converting a function-pointer to an integer, though it will only be a warning and not an error.
Still, heed it!

---

Now after your edit (Calling the function instead of returning it), `return expression;` is still forbidden in `void`-functions (C++ allows it though, for generic programming).

Trying to do so with full warnings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63cc53e798062820

Standard quote (C11):

> #### 6.8.6.4 The `return` statement
>
> Constraints
>   1 A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is `void`. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
>   whose return type is `void`.

Comment: I'm a moron - compiling with `-pedantic` causes a warning. Looks like it's a GCC extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your bar function does not return a void, but a void returning function. Your method must return a function pointer of void.

```
typedef void (*fptr)();

static fptr bar (void) {
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: This is an answer to an older version of the question. See the edited version.