# change FREE preprocessor define to also put null into the pointer

Tags: c, free

I have a preprocessor define:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define FREE(ptr) free(ptr)
```

And I want to know if it is safe to change it to:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define FREE(ptr) free(ptr); \
        (ptr) = null;
```

for code safe.

I think that because free is returning void so it can't be chained as shown at [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332099/returning-void-function-from-a-void-function) so it will be safe, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It won't compile the way you have written it

Comment: I'm also not sure what this has to do with the linked question, your macro doesn't `return` anything (and it also doesn't chain function calls)

Answer (score 2):

Your original is missing a semicolon, and this usage would not work after a control statement (`if`, `else`, `while`, `for`...) if not inside a block statement `{ ... }`.

Since `free` does not return a value, for maximal compatibility (excepting the function pointer use, or use within comma operator. freeing the return value of a function, incrementing in call to free and other dubious tricks...) you could use the very common trick of wrapping into `do { } while (0)`. The `do { } while (0)` will eat the following semicolon, and work alike even in nested `if...else`.

Therefore:

```
#define FREE(ptr) do { free(ptr); ptr = 0; } while (0)
```

Comment: good answer, but still I will have the double evaluation problem that @chux - Reinstate Monica mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Fails in at least 3 ways:

```
#define FREE(ptr) free(ptr) \
    (ptr) = null;
```

`null` not define.

Not tied together. Consider

```
if (test) FREE(ptr);
```

is like

```
if (test) free(ptr);
ptr = null;
```

Double evaluation

```
FREE(foo());
```

is like

```
free(foo());
foo() = null;
```

Comment: for double evaluation perhaps should show the increment operator...

Comment: It would be good to show a solution for the problems.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Edit as you wish, IAC. your answer is a good one, setting aside double evaluation.

Comment: @Bodo `FREE(ptr)` is hiding an assignment.  IMO, there is no _good_ solution.

Comment: I think there won't be double evaluation, but compilation error, no? it is bit better because there won't be problems we don't know about.

Comment: @arye With the macro using `ptr` twice in `free(ptr)` and `(ptr) = ...`, `ptr` is evaluated twice.  If a compilation error or not depends on `ptr`.

Comment: is there is an example where the double evaluation is bad (in current scenario) and ptr is not rvalue? I can think just on some weired scenarios that should not be at ggod code

Comment: @arye The current scenario does not have any code using `FREE(), so I am unable to find any poor examples.

Comment: by current scenario I mean with the macro I suggested in the question, or better with the macro @AnttiHaapala suggested. this macro should be OK in any system and scenario that will use it, assuming proper use of the stdlib free function

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
#define FREE(ptr) do {free(ptr); \
        (ptr) = NULL;} while (0)
```

instead of this:

```
#define FREE(ptr) free(ptr) \
        (ptr) = null;

...
int* a = malloc(10);
printf(" a = %p\n", (void*)a);
FREE(a);
printf(" a = %p\n", (void*)a);
...
```

This code snippet should print something similar to this:

```
a = 01bb95d9
a = 00000000
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for) for more information about the `do... while(0)` stuff.

A cleaner solution would be to put this into a function like this:

```
void FREE(void **ptr)
{
  free(*ptr);
  *ptr = NULL;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int *a = malloc(10);
FREE(&a);
// a is NULL here
```