# Is it possible to make a generic C++ function pointer wrapper with NULL checks?

Tags: c++, function, templates, wrapper, generic-programming

I have to wrap several function pointers which can have NULL values. I'm trying to make a general class template for this, which checks if the function pointer is NULL, calls the original function if pointer is not NULL, and returns a default value if the pointer is NULL. Something like this:

```
//Function typedefs
typedef void(*foo)();
typedef int(*bar)(int u, char *);

//Function pointers
foo gfFoo;
bar gfBar;

//Wrapper class
template<typename T,  typename... Args>
class WrapFuncObj {
    T* f;
public:
    WrapFuncObj(T* t) {
        f = t;
    }
    typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type operator()(Args&&... args) {
        if(f != nullptr){
            return (*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0; //RETURN something for non-void types
        }
    }
};

template<typename T,  typename... Args>
class WrapFuncObjVoid {
    T* f;
public:
    WrapFuncObjVoid(T* t) {
        f = t;
    }
    typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type operator()(Args&&... args) {
        if(f != nullptr){
            (*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        else
        {
            //DO Nothing for void 
        }
    }
};

//Usage:
WrapFuncObjVoid<foo> WrapFoo(&gfFoo);
WrapFoo();
WrapFuncObj<bar, int, char*> WrapBar(&gfBar); 
WrapBar(0, "test");
```

As can be seen, there needs to be separate templates for non-void and void types because in case of null, nothing should be returned if the function pointer is NULL. How to circumvent this problem and make a single template enough for both?

Comment: There is no way to avoid specializing a `void` return type, somewhere.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Yes there is. [In C++ you can return void](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383090/is-returning-void-valid-code).

Comment: If they pass null to the constructor why not just set the pointer to the default function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just `return T();` (assuming `T` is the return type you want). This works for `void` types. It does not work for types with a non-default constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "void foo()\n";
}

 int bar(int u, char* c_str) {
    std::cout << "int bar(" << u << ", \"" << c_str << "\")\n";
    return u;
 }

template<typename T>
class WrapFuncObj;

template<typename T,  typename... Args>
class WrapFuncObj<T(Args...)> {
    T (*f)(Args...);
public:
    WrapFuncObj(T (*t)(Args...)) {
        f = t;
    }

    T operator()(Args&&... args) {
        if(f != nullptr) {
            return (*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } else {
            return T();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    WrapFuncObj<void()> wrap_foo(&foo);
    wrap_foo();

    WrapFuncObj<int(int, char*)> wrap_bar(&bar); 
    wrap_bar(0, "test");

    WrapFuncObj<void()> wrap_null(nullptr);
    wrap_null(); // prints nothing.
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/yk4YLA).

I feel obligated to suggest [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which is what you're trying to reinvent (except you permit calling a null function and return a default type, which may or may not be something you really want to do).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is just what I was looking for. I have read about std::function. However, we have a case where the function pointer may be null as it is an optional function and it's ok for it to return a default value. Many thanks for your help again!