# Why is return throw std::exception() accepted in a void function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, return, prvalue

I mistakenly pasted a `throw` statement after a `return` with the following final result:

```
void DXManager::initialize(const std::shared_ptr<nae::Context>& ctx_ptr)
{
    // ...

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return throw std::exception("Failed to enumerate display mode list");
    }

    // ...
}
```

I successfully built the solution before noticing the mistake, and I'm curious which specification allows the syntax above.

---

By reading [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) (under Notes), I see

> The throw-expression is classified as prvalue expression of type void. Like any other expression, it may be a sub-expression in another expression, most commonly in the conditional operator:
>
> ```
> double f(double d)
>   {
>       return d > 1e7 ? throw std::overflow_error("too big") : d;
>   }
>   // ...
> ```

but I'm not quite sure it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383090/is-returning-void-valid-code

Comment: @StoryTeller's answer to your question is perfectly correct, but regarding the example from cppreference.com: that case is explicitly allowed by the standard [C++14: 5.16/2]: _If either the second or the third operand has type void, one of the following shall hold: The second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression; the result is of the type and value category of the other._ Normally if only one of the second and third operands to a ternary conditional were of void type the code would be invalid, but `throw` is a special case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's because a return statement in a function returning `void`, can have a `void` operand:

> [**[stmt.return]/2**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.return#2)
>
> The *expr-or-braced-init-list* of a return statement is called its operand [...] A return statement with an operand of type `void` shall be used only in
>   a function whose return type is cv `void`.

And as you found out yourself, a `throw` expression has type `void`. This provision is there to make writing generic code smoother. Consider this:

```
template<typename T>
T foo() {
    return T();
}
```

The above rule (along with another rule that defines `void()`) make the above template valid even when instantiated for `void`.